# Draw part of an image?

Tags: image, processing

I am working on a game and I have a sprite sheet of my character, but obviously I just want to draw 1 frame of my characters animations at a time. Is it possible to do so using the image() function?

here is the code (this is for a specific person helping me out)

```
    'PImage spritesheet;
    int DIM_X = 13;
    int DIM_Y = 1;
    PImage[] sprites =  new PImage[DIM_X*DIM_Y];

    void setup() {
     size(300, 300);
     imageMode(CENTER);
     spritesheet = loadImage("PlayerSprites.png");
     int W = spritesheet.width/DIM_X;
     int H = spritesheet.height/DIM_Y;
     for (int i=0; i<sprites.length; i++) {
      int x = i%DIM_X*W;
      int y = i/DIM_Y*H;
      sprites[i] = spritesheet.get(x, y, W, H);
    }
    frameRate(10);
  }

 void draw() {

background(0,0,0);    
image(sprites[frameCount%sprites.length], width/2, height/2);

}'
```

Comment: Please check your tags. The  `image()` function in *what language*?

Comment: it is tagged the language is processing

Comment: Got it. (Perhaps that tag could be changed to something a bit more clear. Then again .. I just had to trick Google in finding *anything* releavant to [image] [processing].) Try http://www.processing.org/reference/imageMode_.html

Comment: I think the tag could be changed, or people could just hover their mouse over the 'processing' tag and see what the heck its about. Every single Processing related question has someone going, "what language is this?!!". You'd think folks with more experience here would know how to do some research before writing off a hasty comment.

Comment: hmmm this seems to just change how to draw an image, like based on the x,y cords you could make that the center of the image or the top left corner.. what im trying to do is say take a 16X16 chunk of the image and just draw that part of it

Comment: You just want to be able to show your character moving using sprite sheet using any means or do you **have** to achieve that using the `image()` function?

Comment: im just asking if you can, I know I can just extract the pixels of the 16X16 grid, just wondering if there is a simpler way

Comment: "Hasty comment", yup. Apologies. OTOH, the OP *could* have thrown in a phrase such as "using Processing" or "in the Processing environment" anywhere in the body or title. "image-processing" (as a single phrase) is a valid tag on SO as well, and describes "anything related to digital image processing".

Comment: alright well seems ill have to extract the pixels and store em in a array

Comment: ohhhhhhh lol it did not tell me that XD

Comment: alright ill remove it XD

Comment: @Mark9135 The `image()` function used to be defined as `image(img, dx, dy, dw, dh, sx, sy, sw, sh);` where `sx, sy, sw, sh` would be the arguments for what part of the image you wanted to display. Now the `image()` function is a lot more limiting though and does not allow that. This isn't guaranteed as I don't have it in my computer but Processing 1.5 might still give you the old `image()` function. The only way to do this now seems to be the way I showed in my answer (if you want, I can undelete it).

Comment: I also asked if it was possible to do with the image() function I did not say I only wanted that the answer using the image get is fine

Comment: EDIT nvm ty for re posting your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will do what you need:

```
PImage spritesheet;
int DIM_X = 6;
int DIM_Y = 5;
PImage[] sprites = new PImage[DIM_X*DIM_Y];

void setup() {
  spritesheet = loadImage("http://payload23.cargocollective.com/1/6/200359/2773164/player_7.png");
  size(300, 300);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  int W = spritesheet.width/DIM_X;
  int H = spritesheet.height/DIM_Y;
  for (int i=0; i<sprites.length; i++) {
    int x = i%DIM_X*W;
    int y = i/DIM_Y*H;
    sprites[i] = spritesheet.get(x, y, W, H);
  }
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw() {
  background(0,0,0);
  image(sprites[frameCount%sprites.length], width/2, height/2);
}
```

There are some things you need to keep in mind:

- `DIM_X` and `DIM_Y` represent how many sprites along x and y are
  there on your sprite sheet. So you need to change those numbers
  accordingly.
- Also the `PImage` is being taken from the internet so, obviously, you
  need to change the `String` for `loadImage()`.
- This is imperfect. You need to tweak it to fit your needs. For
  example, in the sprite sheet that I used, the last row only has three
  instances of the character which results in *flickering* in the
  animation. You need to make sure to compensate for these things in
  your code or make your sprite sheet uniform throughout.
- If you have a sprite sheet with only 1 row. Change this line: `int y
  = i/DIM_Y*H;` to `int y = 1` to reflect that the number of rows does not change.

Comment: @Mark9135 I'll comment here because your question is getting cluttered with comments. So DIM_X is how many times the character appears in a row. So, e.g., the sprite sheet that I use has the character appear 6 times most all rows (except the last one). So DIM_X is 6. Similarly DIM_Y is how many times the character appears in each column, which for most cases for me is 5 times. This is imperfect though since the times the character appears changes in the last row. You have to compensate for that in your sprite sheet or in the code.

Comment: ok but now im getting a weird issue....it wont load my image it keeps saying cant find a method to load PlayerSprites (my image)

Comment: @Mark9135 How are you loading it? Delete it from the data folder and then drag and drop it on your Processing sketch. Sometimes that helps as Processing 2.0+ has had issues reading stuff from data folder manually put there. Not sure if that's the case here but try and see. If this doesn't fix it, let me know how you're loading it and where your image is placed.

Comment: i got it working but now its only showing the first frame....man, did not think it would be this hard EDIT i think my issue is that my sprite sheet is just 1 row of images

Comment: @Mark9135 LOL. Well Processing isn't exactly designed for game development so its got its kinks that need straightening. Are you replacing your image in the code I provided above or did you incorporate it in your own sketch first and then tried to run it? If its the above sketch that I provided, did you change anything other than DIM_X and DIM_Y?

Comment: I needed to change the loadImage bit into the void setup function other then that i simply just changed DIM_X and DIM_Y and im just using your example for now. Also id say different about processing not designed for game dev, though i know its not its main element, the OOP elements work great and is rather easy to use.

Comment: @Mark9135 Okay, changed the code to avoid that problem for later. Can you upload the code somewhere so I can take a look? I have tried this with multiple sprite sheets online and it works. Just have to make sure to enter the correct amounts for DIM_X and DIM_Y. Not sure what's going on with your sketch.

Comment: @Mark9135 Where are you trying to post it? You can update your question and post it there. Then highlight all of the code and click the `{}` on the formatting panel.

Comment: @Mark9135 Also, if you can't share your sprite sheet, lemme know how many rows and columns you got.

Comment: @Mark9135 Ah! I see. The 1 row thing might be screwing it up. Lemme update the code for that and then lemme know if it works for you.

Comment: ill also try moving my sprites into a square and see id that works

Comment: @Mark9135 Before you do anything else. Try to change this line: `int y = i/DIM_Y*H;` to `int y = 1`. And then tell me if that works.

Comment: just wondering what does the % symbol do..I understand everything else expect that lol

Comment: @Mark9135 That's the modulo operator. Its used to find out the remainder. For example, 5/2 gives you 1 as remainder, so if you do `println(5%2)` in Processing, you'll see 1 printed out.

Comment: ahh so you find the remainder of the frame count devided by the amount of sprites and display the remainder?

Comment: @Mark9135 If your sprite sheet always stays at 13x1 then you can change this line `int x = i%DIM_X*W;` to `int x = i * W` and it will still work. But if you are going to add more rows, then keep the `%DIM_X` part.

Comment: oh i see the % is to make sure when you reach the limit of the x positon it wraps back to the beginning